# virt-install on Centos 8.1 doesn't complete when using --location http://localhost/inst

Tags: unattended, virsh, anaconda, centos8, virt-install

Should you reached this before, please let me know.

**ISSUE**

virt-install works well when passing arguments --cdrom /path/to/iso (and creates the guest) like

```
[root@192-168-0-104 admin]#  virt-install --virt-type kvm --name tester2 --memory 2048 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/tester2.qcow2,format=qcow2,size=20,bus=virtio --os-variant generic --os-type linux --cdrom Downloads/CentOS-8.1.1911-x86_64-dvd1.iso --connect qemu:///system --debug  --vnc &
```

whereas using --location http://localhost/inst

```
root@192-168-0-104 admin]# virt-install --virt-type kvm --name tester2 --memory 2048 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/tester2.qcow2,format=qcow2,size=20,bus=virtio --os-variant centos7.0 --location http://localhost/inst --connect qemu:///system --graphics vnc &
```

the guest just created stops at

[ ok ] reached target basic system
and then dracut times out after a while having the following sequence:

dracut-initqueue[941]: Warning: dracut-initqueue timeout - starting timeout scripts

dracut-initqueue[941]: Warning: could not boot

[ ok ] Starting setup virtual console

Starting emergency shell ...

Reached target emergency mode

Warning: /dev/root/ does not exists

Generating "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt"

The GUI of the virtual console of the client doesn't create and it hangs.

**CONDITIONS**

version Centos 8.1

cat /etc/*release|grep rel

CentOS Linux release 8.1.1911 (Core)

firewal stopped, selinux permissive; http server on host listening

The content of the web server with the installation files was copied with and the http local repository has been created with:

dnf install httpd

systemctl enable httpd

systemctl start httpd

cp -apRfv /media/iso/. /var/www/html/inst/

diff -R /media/iso/ /var/www/html/inst/

chcon -R --reference /var/www/ /var/www/html/inst

chmod ugo+wx /var/www/html/inst/

[root@192-168-0-104 admin]# netstat -atunp |grep httpd

tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2137/httpd

(it's 1st time when work somehow seriously with IPv6, where is the IPv4 - tcp simple listener ?)

**LOGS**

Tried to debug

==== The command (with --cdrom = ) with good results:

```
[root@192-168-0-104 admin]#  virt-install --virt-type kvm --name tester2 --memory 2048 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/tester2.qcow2,format=qcow2,size=20,bus=virtio --os-variant generic --os-type linux --cdrom Downloads/CentOS-8.1.1911-x86_64-dvd1.iso --connect qemu:///system --debug  --vnc
```

[1] 17639

[root@192-168-0-104 admin]# [Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:33 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (cli:208) Launched with command line: /usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install --virt-type kvm --name tester2 --memory 2048 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/tester2.qcow2,format=qcow2,size=20,bus=virtio --os-variant generic --os-type linux --cdrom Downloads/CentOS-8.1.1911-x86_64-dvd1.iso --connect qemu:///system --debug --vnc

[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:33 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (virt-install:207) Distilled --network options: ['default']

[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:33 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (virt-install:244) --graphics compat generated: vnc

[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:33 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (virt-install:139) Distilled --disk options: ['path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/tester2.qcow2,format=qcow2,size=20,bus=virtio']

[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:33 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (cli:224) Requesting libvirt URI qemu:///system
[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:33 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (cli:227) Received libvirt URI qemu:///system
[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:33 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (storage:208) refreshing pool=default
[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:33 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (disk:225) Creating volume 'tester2.qcow2' on pool 'default'
[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:33 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (disk:359) disk.set_vol_install: name=tester2.qcow2 poolxml=

  default
  840a9fc8-fa3c-44fc-bf2a-9766f1f91efc
  308013432832
  31819522048
  276193910784
  
  
  
    /var/lib/libvirt/images
    
      0711
      0
      0
      system_u:object_r:virt_image_t:s0

[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:33 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (guest:463) Setting Guest osinfo name <_OsVariant name=generic>
[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:33 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (installer:398) installer.detect_distro returned=None
[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:33 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (guest:463) Setting Guest osinfo name <_OsVariant name=generic>
[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:33 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (virt-install:648) Guest.has_install_phase: True
[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:33 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (cli:272)
Starting install...

Starting install...
[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:33 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (storage:643) Creating storage volume 'tester2.qcow2' with xml:

  tester2.qcow2
  21474836480
  0

[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:33 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (storage:681) Using vol create flags=1
Allocating 'tester2.qcow2'                                                                            |  20 GB  00:00:00
[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:33 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (storage:687) Storage volume 'tester2.qcow2' install complete.
[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:33 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (installer:442) Generated install XML:

  tester2
  212cd18c-b62d-4fe4-bbb1-13eb4921e1fe
  2097152
  2097152
  1
  
    hvm
    
    
  
  
    
    
  
  
  
    
    
    
  
  destroy
  
    
    
  
  
    /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm

[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:33 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (installer:443) Generated boot XML:

  tester2
  212cd18c-b62d-4fe4-bbb1-13eb4921e1fe
  2097152
  2097152
  1
  
    hvm
    
  
  
    
    
  
  
  
    
    
    
  
  
    
    
  
  
    /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm

[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:34 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (installer:497) XML fetched from libvirt object:

  tester2
  212cd18c-b62d-4fe4-bbb1-13eb4921e1fe
  2097152
  2097152
  1
  
    /machine
  
  
    hvm
    
    
  
  
    
    
  
  
    Haswell-noTSX-IBRS
    Intel
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
  
  
    
    
    
  
  destroy
  destroy
  destroy
  
    
    
  
  
    /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm
    
      
      
      
      
      
      
    
    
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
    
    
      
      
    
    
      
      
      
    
    
      
      
      
    
    
      
      
      
    
    
      
    
    
      
      
    
    
      
      
      
      
      
      
    
    
      
      
        
      
      
    
    
      
      
      
    
    
      
      
    
    
      
    
    
      
    
    
      
    
    
      
      
      
    
    
      
      
    
  
  
    system_u:system_r:svirt_t:s0:c590,c764
    system_u:object_r:svirt_image_t:s0:c590,c764
  
  
    +107:+107
    +107:+107

[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:34 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (cli:395) Launching virt-viewer for graphics type 'vnc'
[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:55:34 virt-install 17639] DEBUG (cli:370) Running: virt-viewer --connect qemu:///system --wait tester2
No protocol specified

(virt-viewer:17776): dbind-WARNING **: 07:55:34.530: Could not open X display

(virt-viewer:17776): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 07:55:34.558: g_dbus_proxy_new_sync: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

=== The command (with --location = ) with no results

(same results were obtained when used a public http mirror)

```
root@192-168-0-104 admin]# virt-install --virt-type kvm --name tester2 --memory 2048 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/tester2.qcow2,format=qcow2,size=20,bus=virtio --os-variant centos7.0 --location http://localhost/inst --connect qemu:///system --graphics vnc &
```

[1] 10581

[root@192-168-0-104 admin]#
Starting install...
Retrieving file vmlinuz...                                                                            | 7.7 MB  00:00:00
Retrieving file initrd.img...                                                                         |  59 MB  00:00:00
Allocating 'tester2.qcow2'                                                                            |  20 GB  00:00:00
No protocol specified

(virt-viewer:10739): dbind-WARNING **: 07:01:02.446: Could not open X display

(virt-viewer:10739): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 07:01:02.472: g_dbus_proxy_new_sync: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(cli:227) Received libvirt URI qemu:///system
[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:06:10 virt-install 10931] DEBUG (guest:463) Setting Guest osinfo name <_OsVariant name=generic>

[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:06:10 virt-install 10931] DEBUG (urlfetcher:104) Using scratchdir=/var/lib/libvirt/boot

[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:06:10 virt-install 10931] DEBUG (urldetect:280) Finding distro store for location=http://localhost/inst

[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:06:10 virt-install 10931] DEBUG (osdict:260) Error creating libosinfo tree object for location=http://localhost/inst : g-io-error-quark: Failed to load .treeinfo|treeinfo file: Operation not supported (15)

[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:06:10 virt-install 10931] DEBUG (urlfetcher:139) Fetching URI: http://localhost/inst/.treeinfo

[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:06:10 virt-install 10931] DEBUG (urldetect:71) treeinfo family=CentOS Linux
[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:06:10 virt-install 10931] DEBUG (urldetect:75) Found treeinfo version=8

[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:10:58 virt-install 11310] DEBUG (cli:395) Launching virt-viewer for graphics type 'vnc'

[Mon, 30 Mar 2020 07:10:58 virt-install 11310] DEBUG (cli:370) Running: virt-viewer --connect qemu:///system --wait tester2
No protocol specified

(virt-viewer:11455): dbind-WARNING **: 07:10:58.348: Could not open X display

(virt-viewer:11455): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 07:10:58.371: g_dbus_proxy_new_sync: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

this just went over the initial hang and it started processing anaconda file

```
virt-install --name tester2 --location "ftp://192.168.0.101/pub/inst" --memory 3096 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/tester2.qcow2,size=20,bus=virtio  --os-variant rhel8.1 --extra-args "ks=ftp://192.168.0.101/pub/inst/initial-setup-ks.cfg" --debug &
```